# how we can monitor the non IIS hosted applications using azure application insights?

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-application-insights

I worked with Azure Application Insights from one year onwards. By using application insights I can monitor the azure hosted applications and on- premises IIS hosted applications. But I have doubt like how we can monitor the non IIS hosted applications using azure application insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send telemetry data to Application Insights from a Windows App, use the dedicated [Windows SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop).

You can also use the Application Insights core telemetry API to send custom events and metrics, and your own versions of standard telemetry, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics).